# Oracle: Setting sequence to a specific value

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am using liquibase to manage my schema. I have a bunch of insert statements. I have hard coded the primary-id numbers. After all my inserts are done, I want to change the sequence value to 1 more than the maximum value of the primary-key in the table. For this I wrote a PL/SQL as given below. However, when I execute `select ArtifactTypes_id_seq.nextval from dual;` it still increments 0.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
DECLARE
    sequence_id NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT NVL(MAX(idArtifactType), 0) + 1 INTO sequence_id FROM ArtifactTypes;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY ' || sequence_id;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ArtifactTypes_id_seq.nextval FROM dual';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Executed "ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY ' || sequence_id || '"');
END;
/
```

The DBMS_OUTPUT gives following output -

`Executed "ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY 71"`

Anything that I am missing out? Am I doing the wrong way?
NOte: I tried executing these SQLs from SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found the issue. Following should be the PL/SQL -

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
DECLARE
    sequence_id NUMBER;
    temp_seq NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(MAX(idArtifactType), 0) + 1 INTO sequence_id FROM ArtifactTypes;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY ' || sequence_id;
    SELECT ArtifactTypes_id_seq.nextval into temp_seq FROM dual;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Executed "ALTER SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq INCREMENT BY ' || sequence_id || '"');
END;
/
```

Following statement - 
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ArtifactTypes_id_seq.nextval FROM dual';`

 was changed to 
`SELECT ArtifactTypes_id_seq.nextval into temp_seq FROM dual;`

AND IT WORKED!!

Answer (score 7):

You need to drop the sequence and then re-create it, use the STARTS WITH clause to assign the initial value, eg:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE saas.ArtifactTypes_id_seq
  START WITH 72;
```

Also, selecting the NEXTVAL from a sequence automatically increments it by 1.